# Custom UILabel width based on text length programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I would like to create a `UILabel` that is a little bit wider than the width of the text in the same `UILabel`. I checked a lot of questions and tried the answers from them, but still can't find the right way. I can get the width of the text, but can't redrawn the frame.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

static NSString *Cell = @"cell";
LikeActivityTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];

cell.lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:7.0 green:4.0 blue:55.0 alpha:0.7];

NSString *lblString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", object[@"content"]];
cell.lbl.text = lblString;

float widthIs =  [cell.lbl.text
         boundingRectWithSize:cell.lbl.frame.size
         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:cell.lbl.font }
         context:nil]
        .size.width;


    float heightIs =
        [cell.lbl.text
         boundingRectWithSize:cell.lbl.frame.size
         options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
         attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:cell.lbl.font }
         context:nil]
        .size.height;
NSLog(@"CELL TEXT WIDTH %f", widthIs);

int x = widthIs + 10;
int y = heightIs;
// ATTEMPT 1   
[cell.lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,x,cell.lbl.frame.origin.y)];

// ATTEMPT 2
cell.lbl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, x, cell.lbl.frame.origin.y);

return cell;

}
```

When I run these lines nothing happens, the label doesn't change that I can't understand because it should.

Comment: If you want to change the width, then why do you keep changing the height? And also, the width and height are the same as the x and y? Really? _Really_?

Comment: Are you using auto layout? How is the label positioned originally? Is `cell.lbl` the same as some built-in cell element?

Comment: @matt I've updated the question, I forgot the y value. I'm editing the y value because of test purposes and I'm not so familiar with this sizing stuff. I'm using an auto layout project, but this label doesn't use constraints. I have a custom table view cell class, I created the label there.

Comment: @bushiko using auto layout means you cannot change frame size. all changes to frame size will be ignored.

Comment: @HashmatKhalil I could change the size of a UIView earlier this way, I think it should work too.

Comment: please read the doc. you have misunderstood auto layout: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @bushiko Please show the code _in context_ so that we can see where and how you are calling it. Table views can be tricky to customize. A lot depends on exactly what you say and where you say it.

Comment: @matt I've updated my code. I have a really basic table view, I just wanna display that label correctly.

Comment: this might helps you : http://www.samrayner.com/posts/dynamic-tableview-cells/

Answer (score 3):

You can have the width of the label wrap around the text with just auto layout. If the text is only one line and you want the label size to fit around that, all you have to do is add a constraint that sets the leading attribute or center X (and constraints for the top/Center Y and height) and make sure you add

```
[yourLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
[yourLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal];
```

after adding it to the subview. If the text is multiline or could be multiline you will need a few more lines of code. You will need to set the compression resistance and hug for the vertical axes,

```
[yourLabel setContentCompressionResistancePriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
    [yourLabel setContentHuggingPriority:UILayoutPriorityRequired forAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical];
```

Also add

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    if (!CGRectIsEmpty(self.frame)) {
        _featureDescriptionLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth(self.contentView.frame)-59-5;
    }
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

This goes inside your custom table view cell. Set the max layout width to the widest width the text can be inside of your cell.

Also if it is multiline don't forget to set the number of lines to 0.

Answer (score 3):

There is a very good tutorial for calculation of dynamic height of tableView based on its content. Here the UILabel is extended/customized to fit the dynamic content.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Answer (score 2):

Frame setting is not effective because auto layout is on, try to set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property of the label to `YES` when you set its frame, or you can just turn off auto layout. And 
`[cell.lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,x,cell.lbl.frame.origin.y)];` should be

`[cell.lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,x, heightIs)];`

Answer (score 2):

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CGSize itemTextSize = [@"label text which you want to set" boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 30) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.5]} context:nil].size;
    return itemTextSize.height + 10;


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell =  (UITableViewCell *)[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

    CGSize itemTextSize = [@"label text which you want to set" boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(100, 30) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.5]} context:nil].size;
    itemTextSize.width = itemTextSize.width + 10;
    [cell.lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, itemTextSize.width, itemTextSize.height)];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below methods for cellForRow and for getting size of your text. Hope this will work for you.

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString* cellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";
  UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
 UILabel *lblComment;
 if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        lblComment=[[UILabel alloc] init];
        lblComment.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        lblComment.font=[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE];
        lblComment.numberOfLines=0;
        lblComment.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:lblComment];
}else{
        lblComment=(UILabel *)[[cell.contentView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
 }
  lblComment.tag=[self realRowNumberForIndexPath:indexPath inTableView:tableView] + 0;
  CGSize Comment_Size = [self GetLAbelSize:lblComment.text LabelFont:FONT_NAME width:FONT_SIZE];
  lblComment.frame = CGRectMake(lblComment.frame.origin.x, lblComment.frame.origin.y, Comment_Size.width, Comment_Size.height);
  return cell;
 }

-(CGSize)GetLAbelSize:(NSString *)str_Text LabelFont:(UIFont *)font width:(float)width
{
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(width,MAXFLOAT);
   // CGSize labelSize = [str_Text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
    CGRect boundingRect = [str_Text boundingRectWithSize:constraintSize options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
    CGSize labelSize = boundingRect.size;
    return labelSize;
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CGSize lblComment = [self GetLAbelHeight:[array_Comment objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]  LabelFont:FONT_NAME width:FONT_SIZE];
    float totalHeight = lblComment.height+5;
    return totalHeight;
}


- (NSInteger)realRowNumberForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath inTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
NSInteger retInt = 0;
if (!indexPath.section)
{
    return indexPath.row;
}
for (int i=0; i<indexPath.section;i++)
{
    retInt += [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:i];
}
return retInt + indexPath.row;
}
```

Regards.

Comment: I can retrieve the width and the height. The problem is I can't edit the frame.

Comment: You are using label of UITableViewCell. Please create custom label of your desired properties and then add it to cell.contentView. Then get the label from the content view and then adjust the size. Please review cellForRowAtINdexPath method that i have mentioned above. I request you to please try the same approach as i have mentioned above for label in TableView.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom UITableViewCell. Let's call it CustomCell. Create a XIB, .h and .m for CustomCell. In the XIB, drag a table view cell out so that it is the only thing in the view. Add a label and whatever other views you wish into the cell. Add constraints to the views in whatever way makes sense, and make sure that one of those constraints is a width constraint on the label. Connect this constraint and the label to CustomCell.h. Your CustomCell.h will look like so:

```
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelWidth;

@end
```

Now you can copy/paste the CustomCell from the XIB to the table you want to use the cell in. Then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you can adjust the width of the label as follows, and the other views in the CustomCell will adjust accordingly (thanks, autolayout!).

```
CGSize size = [self.label sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
self.labelWidth.constant = size.width;
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a custom UITableViewCell class and setframe in its "layoutSubviews" method

`-(void)layoutSubviews {

```
[super layoutSubviews]; 

[self.lbl setFrame:...];
```

}`

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to apply proper auto layout constraints for the `UILabel`.Then if your target is iOS 8 , the set tableview's row height property to `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`. 
or

set a height constraint to the `tableview` and in `viewDidAppear`

```
 self.tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
```

in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`
get `tableViewCell` object

```
CGFloat width = label.bounds.size.width;
            if ( label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth != width )
            {
                label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width;

                [tableViewCell setNeedsLayout];
                [tableViewCell layoutIfNeeded];
            }
```

That should do the job if, your auto layout constraints are fine.

Answer (score 1):

Create a fixed width and fixed height constraints on the label (via interface builder), expose them to the view controller (again, via interface builder), and manipulate the layoutconstraints directly:

```
// in the .h created by interface builder
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelWidth;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *labelHeight;
```

...

```
// in the implementation
[self.labelWidth setConstant:widthIs + 10];
[self.labelHeight setConstant:heightIs];
```

Comment: Got this error because of the table view `The labelWidth outlet from the DevTableViewController to the NSLayoutConstraint is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.`

Comment: You added them as separate constraints to the same element?  For now, just try the width, and if that works, add the height constraint afterward.  To add the constraint, highlight the label and select Editor | Pin | Width.  Then, use the Assistant Editor and ctrl-click-and-drag from the constraint (the graphic or from within the Document Outline) to the .h file and add the outlet.

Comment: @bushiko You have to connect the constraints to your `UITableViewCell` subclass, **not** in your view controller!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you create your custom cell like:

```
@implementation LikeActivityTableViewCell
-(id)init{
     self = [super init];
    if(self){
        self.lbl = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        self.lbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:16]; // Set the font you want
        self.lbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:7.0/255 green:4.0/255 blue:55.0/255 alpha:0.7]; // Dont forget "/255"
        [self.contentView addSubview:self.lbl];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Then just try:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *Cell = @"cell";
    LikeActivityTableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cell];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[LikeActivityTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }
    cell.lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Am I cell number %d? No!", indexPath.row * 8]; // Put your text here
    CGSize labelSize = [self getFrameForLabel:cell.lbl];
    labelSize.width += 10.f;
    cell.lbl.frame = CGRectMake(cell.contentView.frame.size.width * 0.5f - labelSize.width * 0.5f,
                                cell.contentView.frame.size.height * 0.5f - labelSize.height * 0.5f,
                                labelSize.width,
                                labelSize.height); // I decided to center the label but you can put 0, 0 as origin
    return cell;
}

-(CGSize)getFrameForLabel:(UILabel*)label{
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: label.font};
    return [label.text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do a similar thing using CustomTableViewCell, by setting translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints of a UILabel property of a custom cell, to true, and then setting the frame of the label to whatever you want by calling customCell.frame = CGRectMake(what, ever, you, want). The only problem with this is that than you will get a warning saying "Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.", until you change translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints to false. This happens when you set your constraints manually through Visual Format. Not sure how to do it through AutoLayout. Im a beginner at this, but thought to share my findings with you anyway, hope it helps a bit. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Check if this one helps..

```
UILabel *type;
type.frame=[self calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:type withText:type.text];

-(CGRect) calculateHeightOfTextFromWidth:(UILabel*)detailLabel withText:(NSString*)text {        

    CGRect currentFrame = detailLabel.frame;
    CGSize max = CGSizeMake(detailLabel.frame.size.width, 500);

    CGSize expected = [text sizeWithFont:detailLabel.font constrainedToSize:max lineBreakMode:detailLabel.lineBreakMode]; 
    currentFrame.size.height = expected.height;
    return currentFrame;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that should return the proper width of your UILabel width based on the height and text string. Set the cell frame with the width returned from this method.

```
CGFloat *maxWidth = the maximum width you would want your label to be
CGFloat *labelHeight = the height of your label
CGFloat *additionalWidthBuffer = any fixed extra width on your label  


-(CGFloat)labelHeightForText:(NSString*) text
{
   UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0f];
   CGFloat width = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(maxWidth, labelHeight)    options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: font} context:nil].size.width;

  return height + additionalWidthBuffer;
}
```